# How to call a JQuery function from button loaded via .load

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue when when i use .load to create some rows of data, each row contains a button called 'deleteaccomm' - this is loaded fine, but the button clickevent wont work.  I have tried .on and also .live

I suspect my syntax when using .live may have been wrong. I was trying it like this:

```
$("#deleteaccom").live('click', function() {
```

**This is the code that makes the ajax call (it resides in an ajax loaded Jquery UI tab)**

```
    $('#save-quote-accomm').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "tabs/quote-addaccomm.asp",
            data:  $("#formaccomm").serialize(),
            cache: false,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(responseText){
                $.ajaxSetup ({
                    cache: false
                });

                var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='images/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";
                var loadUrl = "../includes/accommq.asp?Planner_ID=22A";
                $("#accommadded").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
            },
            error: function(responseText){
            },
        });

    return false;
    });
```

**This is the code (also residing in the ajax loaded tab) that is supposed be called when clicking the button #deleteaccomm**

```
$("#deleteaccomm").click(function( event ) {
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "tabs/accomm-delete.asp",
                data :{
                    pid : $("#deleteaccomm").attr("title")              
                },
                cache: false,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(responseText){
                    alert('deleted');
                },
                error: function(responseText){
                    alert(data);
                },
            });

        return false;
        });
```

I am quite new to Jquery and would welcome some suggestions on where I am going wrong. I also wonder if I am placing my Jquery in the correct files (ie. should it all reside on the top level page that contains my JQuery UI tabs - or place in the files that are loaded into the tabs)

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if using jQuery >= 1.7 use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (live is deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9)

```
$("#accommadded").on('click', '#deleteaccomm', function(){
    .....
})
```

if using jQuery < 1.7 && >= 1.4.2 use [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$("#accommadded").delegat('#deleteaccomm', 'click', function(){
    .....
})
```

Comment: ok - thats worked, just so i understand why - Is it essentially referencing the button via the id of the loaded content div #accommadded ?

Comment: @Borami when we are adding the click handler the button does not exists in the dom so we cannot add a handler to that element, instead what we are doing to to add the handler to once of the ancestor element which already exists in the page and then tell the jQeury framework that fire the handler only if the event is originated from an element with id `deleteaccomm`. Hope this makes it clear